# Converting Display Member Property to Upper Case

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm using the following query to return results from an access database. Within the column "DocName" there is a mix of strings that are Upper Case, Lower Case & and combination of both. Unfortunately I do not have access to amend the database so would like to convert the "Display Member" to ideally Proper Case but if not possible Upper Case. I have seen the .ToUpper options but can't get it to work. Any Ideas

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("", "")
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim conn As String


            Dim eSearch As String = AllDetails(n).uCode

            conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Me.aClients & ""

            da.SelectCommand.Connection.ConnectionString = conn
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT DocName FROM Documents WHERE (UnitCode = " & eSearch & ") AND (Required = True)"
            da.Fill(dt)
            lstRequired.DataSource = dt
            lstRequired.DisplayMember = "DocName"
            lstRequired.Refresh()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as the query in your command:

```
da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT UCASE(DocName) AS DocNm FROM Documents WHERE (UnitCode = " & eSearch & ") AND (Required = True)"
```

There is a UCase function that retrieves all data in upper case if it is a string.

Update: Based on your comment to another question, now your returned column is no longer named DocName. Use the line of code above to replace your code that sets the command text, and then replace your line of code that sets the DisplayMember property with the line of code below:

```
lstRequired.DisplayMember = "DocNm"
```

I explicitly set the column name to DocNm of your newly-created column and changed the DisplayMember property to the new column name.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it at the commandtext or iterate through the table and update each row's DocName column with .ToUpper().

I believe with that provider you can use uCASE

```
da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT UCASE(DocName) as DocName FROM Documents WHERE (UnitCode = " & eSearch & ") AND (Required = True)"
```

if not UCASE try UPPER(DocName) as DocName

Comment: Thanks, UCASE returns to the ListBox "System.Data.DataRowView" in replace to the string and UPPER returns as an Undefined function

Comment: @elmonko, see my answer above, I just updated it. Hopefully it'll help.

Comment: yes you need to add the alias else the UCASE function just returns the string and the column has no name.